# Filling a matrix with vectors in loop and apply operation

Tags: matlab

I am working on matlab with a matrix. I would like to reproduce this matrix and apply sum for elements in rows.

[image]

I have two vectors defined by this code:

```
unitsvector=1:5;
reordervector=1:3;
```

Then, I create an empty matrix to store the values:

```
resultvec=zeros(size(unitsvector,2)*size(reordervector,2),3);
```

Finally, here is the loop I use but it is not working:

```
for a=1:length(resultvec)
    for b=reordervector
        for c=unitsvector
            resultvec(a,1)=b;
            resultvec(a,2)=c;
            resultvec(a,3)=b+c;
        end
    end
end
```

How could I reproduce this matrix in matlab. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `meshgrid` for this without a for loop.

```
[a,b] = meshgrid(1:5,1:3); 
M = [a(:) b(:)];
M(:,3) = sum(M,2); % Create third column by summing first two
```

Comment: I hadn't even considered the actual vector creation, I missed that. Good job catching it, your answer is much better than mine now.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looping at all? [`sum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) actually has vector support; a simple `resultvec = [a(:,1),a(:,2),sum(a,2)]` would work.

---

As to your code: of course it doesn't work. What do you expect to be the contents of `a`? You create `a` as a loop index, which runs over the range `1:length(resultvec)`. Ergo, within each loop iteration `a` is a scalar. You try to call it like it is a three-element vector. Nor do you define `b` and `c`. This might be possible in R, judging where you're coming from, but not in MATLAB.